# Get item type and other metadata in AppleScript

Tags: applescript

In AppleScript, how can I list an object's "metadata" (or what's the right terminology in AppleScript?), and how do I get "type" metadata for an object?

In other word, how can I implement these functions:

```
on GetType(x)
    return ??? -- returns "window" if x is a window
end GetType

on ListMetadata(x)
    repeat ??? -- enumerate through "name", "(what is it for type)", etc.
       ...
    end repeat
end ListMetadata
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first function can be accomplished with

```
on GetType(x)
    return class of x as text
end GetType
```

Metadata are *properties* in AppleScript, however properties are not required and the type of properties is a record (dictionary) which cannot be simply enumerated in a repeat loop.